# R saving contour lines into a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot allows me to plot contour lines for a data series x and y:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=c(1:100),y=rnorm(100))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_density2d()
```

I would like to be able to save the data output of the main four contour lines (95,75,50,25)max and (95,75,50,25)min in a  dataframe.
I would be grateful for your help.
Perhaps there is a way of doing this directly, without using ggplot.

Comment: There are no contour lines in the output of that ggplot()-call. It retruns that data and the directions to do the calculations and plotting but not the results.

Comment: The title does not really reflect the question...

Answer (score 5):

Using function `ggplot_build(`) around `ggplot()` object you can access all data used for the plotting. Data are stored in list element `data`.

```
p<-ggplot_build(ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_density2d())

str(p$data)
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   1895 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ level: num [1:1895] 5e-04 5e-04 5e-04 5e-04 5e-04 5e-04 5e-04 5e-04 5e-04 5e-04 ...
  ..$ x    : num [1:1895] 1 2 3 4 5 ...
  ..$ y    : num [1:1895] 1.42 1.44 1.45 1.45 1.46 ...
  ..$ piece: int [1:1895] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ group: Factor w/ 13 levels "1-001","1-002",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ PANEL: int [1:1895] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

You can store those data as separate data frame.

```
gg<-p$data[[1]]
head(gg)
  level        x        y piece group PANEL
1 5e-04 1.000000 1.423926     1 1-001     1
2 5e-04 2.000000 1.435286     1 1-001     1
3 5e-04 3.000000 1.445293     1 1-001     1
4 5e-04 4.000000 1.454166     1 1-001     1
5 5e-04 5.000000 1.462106     1 1-001     1
6 5e-04 5.255343 1.463967     1 1-001     1
```

`group` and `piece` variables shows for which line each value belong (1 - outer lines, 13 - inner lines in this case).